# Postgresql update column with integer values

Tags: postgresql

I've a column with jsonb type and contains list of elements either in string or integer format.
What I want now is to make all of them as same type e.g either all int or all string format

**Tried:** this way I get single element but I need to update all of the elements inside of the list.

```
SELECT parent_path -> 1 AS path
    FROM abc
    LIMIT 10
```

**OR**

```
Update abc SET parent_path = ARRAY[parent_path]::TEXT[] AS parent_path
FROM abc
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE abc SET parent_path = replace(parent_path::text, '"', '') where id=123
```

**Current Output**

```
         path
[6123697, 178, 6023099]
[625953521394212864, 117, 6023181]
["153", "6288361", "553248635949090971"]
[553248635358954983, 178320, 174, 6022967]
[6050684, 6050648, 120, 6022967]
[653, 178238, 6239135, 38, 6023117]
["153", "6288496", "553248635977039112"]
[553248635998143523, 6023185]
[553248635976194501, 6022967]
[553248635976195634, 6022967]
```

**Expected Output**

```
        path
[6123697, 178, 6023099]
[625953521394212864, 117, 6023181]
[153, 6288361, 553248635949090971]   <----
[553248635358954983, 178320, 174, 6022967]
[6050684, 6050648, 120, 6022967]
[653, 178238, 6239135, 38, 6023117]
[153, 6288496, 553248635977039112]   <----
[553248635998143523, 6023185]
[553248635976194501, 6022967]
[553248635976195634, 6022967]
```

**Note:** Missing double quotes on the list. I've tried several methods from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) but no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to unnest them, cleanup each element, then aggregate it back to an array:

The following converts all elements to integers:

```
select (select jsonb_agg(x.i::bigint order by idx)
        from jsonb_array_elements_text(a.path) with ordinality as x(i, idx)
       ) as clean_path
from abc a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scalar subquery to select, unnest, and aggregate the elements:

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT row_number() over () as id, col::JSONB
    FROM (VALUES ('[6123697, 178, 6023099]'),
                 ('["6123697", "178", "6023099"]')) as bla(col)
)
SELECT id, (SELECT JSONB_AGG(el::int) FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(col) as el)
FROM mytable
```